# date variables in php

Tags: php, datetime

I've written a code for appending the date, month and year variables that are stored in three different variables into an array, and I used the implode function to change that into an appropriate date format; but that is not showing the output as expected.
The code is as follows:

```
$year = 2012;
$month1 = $_POST["month1"];
$date = $_POST["date"];
$array[] = "{$year}{$month1}{$date}";   
$imp = implode('/',$array);
echo $imp;
```

here `$date` and `$month1` are taken from the form....
the output is displaying as `20121220` but not as `2012/12/20`.

What's wrong with the above code?

Comment: $array = array($year,$month1,$date); rather than $array[] = "{$year}{$month1}{$date}";

Comment: Suggest you read about array handling functions as well as date functions

Comment: Suggest you read about basic string operations as well...

Comment: Agree with Mark. There are plenty of PHP Date functions to utilize.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$array[] = "{$year}{$month1}{$date}";
```

Is a valid construct for an array, but it's not the one you would like to have. It creates an array with one element which consists of a string.

With your implode function you want to implode several different elements to one, so every part of the date should be an element. Like this:

```
$array = array($year, $month1, $date);
```

Comment: `$array[] = "{$year}{$month1}{$date}";` is valid, just not the way the OP is expecting for his usage.

Comment: I added some more details to reflect your comments.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the misleading information, it's funny how these easy questions can reveal our own ignorance or naivety sometimes (not picking on you specifically, it happens a lot - someone asked how to interpolate a PHP variable into HTML the other day and had 5 wrong answers within 60 seconds).

Comment: thanks all for giving responses.....i tried as the way u guys suggested then "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in /home/dtestfor/public_html/datecalculations.php on line 6" is showing...wat to do?

Answer (score 3):

You are not putting each item in an array. You are creating a single string. To put it an an array is to do:

```
$arr = array($year, $month1, $date);
```

However, why not just do

```
$result = "{$year}/{$month1}/{$date}";
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

```
$result = sprintf("%04d/%02d/%02d", $year, $month, $date);
```

Comment: Using sprintf for this? Why not cut to the chase and just `echo "$year/$month/$date";`? While this is certainly *valid*, I don't think it's of any real help to the OP, judging by the code in the post.

Comment: I was working on the assumption they wanted to enforce leading zeros in the date. This will do that.

Comment: Ah that is relevant, but in this *particular* case it doesn't matter since POST data is always a string (or array of strings). I suppose you could have clarified that when posting your answer, this is basically just a one-liner with no explanation. Obviously the OP is confused and needs some hand-holding.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$array` isn't set as you expect. Try:

```
$array = array($year, $month1, $date);
$imp = implode('/',$array);
echo $imp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried..

```
$array = array($year,$month1,$date);   
$imp = implode('/',$array);
```

Comment: That is not correct! With $array[] you're creating a sub-array within array. Try var_dump($array) to show what i mean.

Comment: Copy paste mistake. changed now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

`$array[] = "{$year}{$month1}{$date}";` has a couple of problems:

1) Arrays are represented like this:

```
array($year, $month1, $date);
```

2) Arrays are assigned without the `[]`

So you want to say

```
$array = array($year, $month1, $date);
```

Comment: `$array[] = "test"` is the same as `$array = array("test");` How can you say "2) Arrays are assigned without the []?"

Comment: @Blake: Array **elements** are assigned with `[]`, not arrays.

Comment: And PHP will instantiate the array if you add an element to it. You don't have to explicitly declare a `new Array`